# is there something like background-margin?

Tags: css

I'm used to position divs X px from the middle like this:

```
#theDiv
{
    position:       absolute;
    top:            50%;
    left:           50%;
    margin-top:     -50px;
    margin-left:    -100px;
}
```

Now I want to archive something similiar with my body background:

```
body
{
    background-position:    50% 50%;
    /*background-margin-top:    -100px from the middle...*/

}
```

I know how this can be achieved with an additional div and using z-indexes,
but is there really not an easier approach?

Comment: don't think you can do this unfortunately, at least not with js

Comment: Nope, no `background-margin-top`, sorry. But you can reposition background with js...

Comment: @iceteea the answer is no but did you try less or sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [less.js](http://lesscss.org) (or SASS) to calculate the position of the image.

*Totally untested* but something like this might work:

```
body
{
    background-position: 50%-100px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`background-position: center;` will center the background image without the nedd of any hacks or workarounds like yours.

Comment: Might be true, but what are doing rather than centering a background-image? Maybe there is another solution for the task you are trying to accomplish beyond one's own nose.